# Error - ''Main method not found in class Node, please define the main method as...." in the following code:

Tags: java

Exact error: "Error: Main method not found in class Node, please define the main method as:
public static void main(String[] args)
or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application"

```
class Node{
    int key;
    Node left, right;

    public Node(int item){
        key = item;
        left = right = null;
    }
}

class BinaryTree{
    Node root;

    BinaryTree(){
        root = null;
    }

    void printPostorder(Node node){
        if(node == null)
            return;
        
        printPostorder(node.left);
        printPostorder(node.right);
        System.out.print(node.key + " ");
    }

    void printPostorder(){ printPostorder(root);}

    public static void main(String[] args){
        BinaryTree tree = new BinaryTree();
        tree.root = new Node(1);
        tree.root.left = new Node(2);
        tree.root.right = new Node(3);

        System.out.println("\nPostorder: ");
        tree.printPostorder();
    }
}
```

But the main function has been defined.

Comment: "But the main function has been defined." yes, but not in the `Node` class, in what appears to be a file called `Node.java`

Comment: You can also run as   java BinaryTree

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you've named the java file as "Node.java" instead of "BinaryTree.java", the code throws error since there isn't any main function in `class Node` (that you're trying to run) but in `class BinaryTree`. The problem shall resolve if you rename your file to BinaryTree.